# Github action build trigger for docker image with specific command in commit message

Tags: docker, github-actions, commit-message

i am using github action to build my project via docker image plugin, my main branch is master branch so i wanna trigger my build only if there is special message in commit message for ex [ci build], previously I used jenkins to build my project where i can achieve this with commit message trigger plugin in jenkins, i wanna do same thing with github action but can not find any documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out https://github.com/rlespinasse/git-commit-data-action. With this action you can expose commit data inside your action